# Selenium test stopped working for IE11

Tags: selenium-webdriver, ie11

I have several tests running, using the InternetExplorer Webdriver and Java to do the logic.

All of the sudden, there is 1 test that starts failing.
While investigating, I find that the webdriver can't find any details about the elements that I try interacting with.
It finds the elements xpath, but no innerHTML or outerHTML, and weirdly, no page source either.

The page I'm interacting with is a popup that is launched from a popup, which is launched from the main site.

I'm using IE11 and Webdriver 3.14.

I found a historical issue where the same behaviour was caused by an update by microsoft, which I recently received as well.

I'm limited in what I can do:

- I can't uninstall IE, or the update as I'm using a company laptop
- I can't switch to another browser as I'm using a company laptop
- I can't change the site, as it is supplied by an external firm

I can switch Drivers

I've tried reverting to older drivers, as that was a concurrent change that happened, but to no avail.

I've tried playing with the security settings, but again, since it is a company laptop, there is not too much that I can do.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have the problem anymore, I'm going to self answer:

- I added some waits in the process, to make sure the page is fully loaded every time.
- I upgraded my driver from 3.14 to 3.15

Comment: You can also accept your own answers :)

Comment: @NielsvanReijmersdal, I still have to wait 21h